# Firebase how to see Cloud Storage triggers on local

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

Is it possible to see Cloud Storage triggers on my local? I'm running `firebase serve` for example: I'd like to see image upload triggers on my node console

```
exports.generateThumbnail = functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object) => {
    console.log(object);
    return;
});
```

Currently I'm deploying every time when I test something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emulator currently doesn't reflect actual changes to your project.  If you want to test a trigger locally, use the documentation to learn about how to [invoke functions locally](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator).  You can also [unit test functions locally](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing).