# Cannot scope Firebase Cloud Storage Function to a specific bucket on the local emulator

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to test a Firebase Cloud Storage triggered cloud function using the local Firebase emulator. Part of the requirement of this function is that it's scoped to a specific storage bucket (ie not the default one). However, despite creating this additional bucket in the Storage Emulator UI, whenever I upload a file to *any* bucket (not just the scoped one) the cloud function runs...

Does anyone have any experience with this? Or is scoping Storage Functions simply not supported on the local emulator.

Comment: Do you have any documents or guides that you followed in creating your bucket? So that we can check if you've missed a part of it, and the other community members can assist you.

Comment: I simply made a new bucket in the local emulator

Answer (score 0):

According in the [documentation for triggering Cloud Functions from Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events):

Use `functions.storage` to create a function that handles Cloud Storage events:

`functions.storage.bucket('bucketName').object()` to listen for object changes on a specific bucket.

> Or is scoping Storage Functions simply not supported on the local emulator.

Also tried this, and got callbacks to all functions, regardless of the bucket, and was able to reproduce this issue. As of now, the Cloud Storage emulator currently does not support any [bucket-level](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_storage#bucket-level_metadata) configuration including storage class, bucket-level CORS configuration, labels, or retention policies. Firebase intends to improve this support over time.

There's also a helpful related SO questions that can provide you more details in this matter:

1. [Can I run Firebase Storage cloud functions locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56804018/16531380)
2. [Firebase how to see Cloud Storage triggers on local](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54284618/16531380)

You can also create a feature request, here's the [link](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features) where you can submit your feature request.

Comment: Yeah, I've since found and reported this on the Firebase Tools github repo. There's an outstanding PR that fixes this: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3932.